Prevent duplicates using Sf flow
I'm new to flow.. I am trying to build a flow..in the org some products have blank serial number custom text field)  and some have the same serial number( duplicates ). (Current duplicates and blanks are staying and not going to be removed). The new requirement is to show the message/error when the product is created OR updated and when the user tries to insert the same serial number then the message /error is fired. That should fire when the user tries to update the serial number to the existing one in the org too. The serial number can be blank too. I can't use matching/ duplicate rules. I don't know what should I add as a resource in Custom error. What am I missing and what is wrong in these elements? Thank you so much !

The Decision should have the criteria:
SN Online equals $Record.SN AND
Id not equal $Record.Id AND
SN Online Is Null $GlobalConstant.FALSE

If you find the record, it's a duplicate.
In addition, you need to move the Custom Error to the "isNotNull" decision branch. Your current design always triggers.

Edit: Flow design


Thanks @sfdvfox. Just to clarify: so no entry conditions on the product object, then get records then decision with criteria you mentioned then custom error element. Can you please visualise what you mean by" In addition, you need to move the Custom Error to the "isNotNull" decision branch. Your current design always triggers." Thank you, appreciate your help a lot.

@sfsun You can either filter in the Start element, or the decision element. There's not much difference in performance. See my edit to see what the flow should look like.

Hi @sfdcfox can you please show start, decision and custom error elements  please? I don't seem to add these criteria. Thank you

@sfsun My criteria don't reflect your object; the screenshot is to demonstrate how the elements should be laid out. The Start element can use the filter mentioned by Miguel, or not, the Decision can use the criteria I mentioned above, and the error element just adds a message to the record. It'd be more helpful if you edited your own question with updated screenshots so we can see where you're stuck.

My suggestion:

Since you are allowing records to have a blank SN, you can make your entry criteria fire only when SN_Online__c Is Null False that way it ignores records with a blank SN
On your get records element, use the criteria that sfdcfox provided in his answer (though if you do Step 1 above, you could ommit the third condition, since that is factored in the Entry Crtieria already). My suggestion would be to store only the first record (explained below)
Your decision element looks good as is (as far as I can read), but you want to make sure your Custom Error is only reached from the isNotNull path, otherwise the decision is pointless, since both paths go to the custom error (this is what sfdcfox was referrring to).
Your custom error can include details about the existing record to point users to view the existing product. For example, your error message could say


You are trying to create a duplicate record. Product #XXXXXXX titled
XXXXXXXXX already exists with Serial Number XXXXXXX. Please edit the existing record instead

Those XXXXX can be merge fields from the existing record you already found. This is why I recommend to get only the first record in step 2.

Hi @Miguel Diaz, thank you, still something is not right:

Miguel Diaz, thank you, something is still not right ..the flow is working when I create a new product with an existing serial number (the error fires)but when I edit the existing product and edit the serial number to the existing one, the error doesn't fire

Is the flow not getting triggered at all? Or is your interview following the default outcome without the error? Without knowing your exact setup, it's hard for me to say, but I'd debug with the following approach: 1) Check if flow is triggered or not in the first place 2) identify all variables required for the interview to take the desired error path and one by one figure out which one(s) your record is NOT meeting 3) Could have something to do with how you have the flow running for fast field updates (before save) in the entry criteria. Try setting to after save (Actions and Related Records)


Try with different records 5) ensure your Serial Numbers are actually the same when testing. Maybe having a blank space somewhere might make it seem that it is the same number but it really isnt

